# Ionic 1 caching js lib

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've inherited an ionic 1 app and i have a strange problem with it. I've updated a js lib (paho mqtt client), because it was an old version that had problems. I've tested the update with lots of android emulators with all sorts of apis. Everything works fine.

The problem is that when i install it on the real phone, it still uses the old js library. But this only happens on phones that had the previous app version installed. If i install it on any phone (no matter the android version) that never had the app installed, everything works perfectly.

I'm thinking that the phones that had the app are somehow caching that js lib or something. I have cleared the app's cache, data, uninstalled it. It makes no difference.

Is there any other cache that i could clear?

Thank you

**Update**

The js and css files are concatenated into one file. This is what i have in the gruntfile:

```
// concat all the scripts in one and all the styles in one
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ''
      }
      ,
      'scripts': {
        src: [
          'app/js/app.js',
          'app/js/controllers/*.js',
          'app/js/services/*.js',
          'app/js/filters/*.js',
          'app/js/directives/*.js',
        ],
        dest: 'www/scripts/scripts<%= grunt.option(\"timestamp\") %>.min.js',
      }
      ,
      'libraries': {
        src: [
          'app/libraries/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js',
          'app/libraries/angular-material/angular-material.js',
          'app/libraries/ion-datetime-picker/ion-datetime-picker.min.js',
          'app/libraries/angular/angular-aria.js',
          'app/libraries/angular/angular-filter.js',
          'app/libraries/angular/angular-translate.js',
          'app/libraries/moment.js',
          'app/libraries/moment-timer.js',
          'app/libraries/leaflet/leaflet.js',
          'app/libraries/oms.min.js',
          'app/libraries/mqtt31.js',
          'app/libraries/angular-cookies.min.js',
          'app/libraries/dropzone/dropzone.js',
          'app/libraries/dropzone/ngdropzone/ng-dropzone.min.js',
        ],
        dest: 'www/scripts/libraries.min.js',
      }
      ,
      'styles': {
        src: [
          'app/libraries/ionic/css/ionic.min.css',
          'app/libraries/angular-material/angular-material.css',
          'app/libraries/ion-datetime-picker/ion-datetime-picker.min.css',
          'app/libraries/leaflet/leaflet.css',
          'app/libraries/magic.css',
          'app/libraries/dropzone/ngdropzone/dropzone.css',
          'app/libraries/dropzone/ngdropzone/ng-dropzone.min.css',
          'app/css/*.css',
        ],
        dest: 'www/resources/css/styles<%= grunt.option(\"timestamp\") %>.min.css',
      }
      ,
      'libsAndScripts': {
        src: [
          'www/scripts/libraries.min.js',
          'www/scripts/scripts<%= grunt.option(\"timestamp\") %>.min.js',
        ],
        dest: 'www/scripts/scripts<%= grunt.option(\"timestamp\") %>.min.js',
      }
    }
```

Then the resulting js file is included in the app from the `index.html`:

```
<script src="scripts/scripts1570989249364.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is the library included in the Ionic app?

Comment: @yazantahhan I've updated my questions with the details. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, this was not a problem with ionic/android caching stuff, but with some very complicated and buggy way of handling users and passwords on the mqtt broker that lead to not being able to properly connect with the paho mqtt lib from the ionic app in some cases.